# Dm everyone in a function and sends a complete message when it's done

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to send all the members in a server every 10 min a dm in a specific server. And when it send all the members it wil send a complete message in the console.

- But it says member.send is not a function
- And I want also in a specific server

```
if (command === `${prefix}dmall`) {

    var list = bot.guilds.array();
    sendMessage(list);
  }
});



function sendMessage(list) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      let member = list.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length), 1);
      member.send("Test")
      list.length = list.length - 1;

      if (list.length = 0)
        console.log("Done")
    }


    sendMessage(list);
  }, 10 * 1000);

}

bot.login(botconfig.token);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (command === `${prefix}dmall`) {
   let myGuild = bot.guilds.get('YOU guild HERE')
     let list = myGuild.members.map(member => member.user.id)
    sendMessage(list, myGuild);
  }
});



function sendMessage(list, myGuild) {
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    setTimeout((function(index){ 
      return function() {
                var member = myGuild.members.get(list[index])
                if(!member.user.bot && member) {
                    member.send('asdsadsa').catch(console.log('Member not allow to send him DM message'))
                }
        if(index === list.length-1) console.log('done')
      };
    })(i), 10000 * (i + 1))
  }
}

bot.login(botconfig.token);
```

Answer (score 0):

In you code **list** its not a list of guild members, its array with 1 guild collection.
So when you try to send message, you try send it to array.
If you have the server ID where you want to send the dm message, you can do it like this

```
if (command === `${prefix}dmall`) {

    let dmGuild = bot.guilds.get('GUILD ID HERE')
    dmGuild.members.map(member => {
        member.send('YOUR MESSAGE')
        .catch('Member not allowed to recive DM message from this server')
    })    
});
```

Comment: Its sends now every time to me but i want to send it 1 time and then to the next person and when its done it will send a complete message in the console.

Comment: whats message you send?
Bot spam this message many times to your DM?

Comment: Yess I know but I won't that it spams to the same person so I want every 10 min but it only sends to mine I want to send it to random people and just 1 dm per person. And when it dm'ed all the members it will send a complete message. And then it will stop the function.

Comment: hmm, okay if code logic right, this solution must work

Comment: oops, sorry, misssing join after splice array, i`m edit code in my secont answer

Comment: Nvm I think its working now you have to put 1 more = in  if (list.length = 0)

Comment: list.length == list.length - 1;
  
      if (list.length == 0)
        console.log("Done")
    }

Comment: If I do 1 = its not working and if I do 2 == by if (list.length == 0)
        console.log("Done") it says only to me and then gives a error by list.length == list.length - 1; and if I do == by the 2 It sends everyone in 1 time and not with 10 sec

Comment: Okay, why you use setTimeout here? Set time out dont let you call any function more than 1 time for constanted timeout. Why you need cycle at start of the function? If i right understand your , you need to send a DM message to every guild member with some cooldown? And write console.log when message will be send to all guild users

Comment: So it's better if I do it with a interval in stead of a sendMessage function?

Comment: Try the last updated code, i test it in my guild and its work fine

Comment: It's spamming everyone again... But sometimes it work? Is it because I used a acc instead of a bot?

Comment: It says "This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch()."

Comment: i`m sorry about long answer, show me pls your command handle bot